# How do I replace string type with date type in MongoDB for an object array?

Tags: mongodb

I know the method for converting dates for the first level

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(x){ 
x.DateField = ISODate(x.DateField); 
db.collection.save(x);})
```

This works with first level fields, but what should I do if i want to change fields of objects in arrays such as `CreatedTime` in the below json sample:

```
{
    "Pharmacy": "b",
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 60,
        "CreatedTime" : "2006-05-05T11:44:47.86Z"
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedC",
        "Quantity": 34,
        "CreatedTime" : "2006-11-23T12:28:44.86Z"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cursor from the aggregate query and bulk updates to update documents in 4.0 version.

Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) to keep the existing values and convert the string date to date type.

Here is the shell sample.

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
var batch = 50; // Change batch size as you need

db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
       "Medicine":{
         "$map":{
            "input":"$Medicine",
            "in":{
                "MedName":"$$this.MedName",                                  
                "Quantity":"$$this.Quantity",
                "CreatedTime":{"$toDate":"$$this.CreatedTime"}
            }
          }
       }
   }}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    bulk.find( {"_id" : doc._id}).updateOne(
     { "$set": {"Medicine" : doc.Medicine}} 
   ); 
    count++;  
    if (count == batch) { 
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
        count = 0;
    } 
});

if (count > 0) { 
   bulk.execute(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('test').find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.Medicine.forEach(function(doc1){
        var dbl = new Date(doc1.CreatedTime);
        doc1.CreatedTime = dbl;
    });
    db.test.save(doc);
});
```

**EDITED: =======** Second approach: [Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)

```
db.logmessages.aggregate( [ {
    $project: {
       date: {
          $dateFromString: {
             dateString: '$date',
             timezone: 'America/New_York'
          }
       }
    }
} ] )
```

Comment: @Acex, This is tested query.

Comment: Wait what was the operator that allows me to read a string as a date?

Comment: Sorry? Didn't get you.

Comment: Your `CreatedTime` is in `String`. You just need to iterate on each document, get all `String` date and then just assign Date to `CreatedTime`. and then just save it. It will change your `String` date to `Date` object

Comment: The second approach that you erased, is actually more helpful for me. 
Although it does not answer the question completely